# The inRequestScope is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, inversifyjs

Help using inRequestScope inversifyJS
Eg:

```
container.bind<ITransactionManager>(Types.MysqlTransactionManager).to(MysqlTransactionManager).inRequestScope()

...
container.get<ITransactionManager>(Types.MysqlTransactionManager)//call the MysqlTransactionManager constructor and return the instance

container.get<ITransactionManager>(Types.MysqlTransactionManager) //call the constructor one more time and return a new instance
```

I want the same instance to be returned when the get is called for the second time instead of instantiating it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap both `.get` calls in a single class and **then** resolve the class using `.get` or `.resolve`

**Excerpt from documentation**

> Each call to one of this methods will resolve a root dependency and all its sub-dependencies. Internally, a dependency graph known as the "resolution plan" is created by InversifyJS. The inRequestScope scope will use one single instance for objects that appear multiple times in the resolution plan. This reduces the number of required resolutions and it can be used as a performance optimization in some cases.

https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/scope.md